# I do not know failure validation app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm getting the following error when validating my application in xcode and know if it is allowed or not occupy this plugin in a hybrid application with phonegap.

[image]

The problem is that if I delete any reference to this library lose my app notifications, anyone know how to fix it? I have extremely troubled this.

Comment: have you tried asking urbanairship?

Comment: the truth not know that, you can guide me ??

Comment: I don't know UrbanAirship and I do not own an account, but surely you will find a "Support" link or "Help" or even "Contact us". There you'll be able to email them and maybe link to this question.

Comment: if you are using the urbanairship plugin, make sure you are using the latest version and contact urban airship team. If you are not using it, remove the plugin

Comment: I delete the plugin but the error is.

Comment: you can put it in response to dial, clean the project and everything worked. Thank You :) @jcesarmobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the urbanairship plugin, make sure you are using the latest version and contact urban airship team. If you are not using it, remove the plugin. Make sure you clean the project after removing the plugin.